# check for 4xx Http Code with native Java

Tags: java, http

I have some java code which checks a http response. Now, I would like to check the code against the client error (4xx) family, how can I do that?

```
int responseCode = ab.sendGetRequest(href);
```

The simplest solution would be:

```
if (400 <= responseCode && responseCode < 500 ){
   //...
}
```

or a bit nicer in terms of coding conventions but giving readability a big hit:

```
if (HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST <= responseCode && 
    responseCode < HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

How can I check `responseCode` against the `4xx` family somehow like the following...

```
CLIENT_ERROR.contains(code)
```

The important point is, that I *don't want to* use a custom solution (writing my own `CLIENT_ERROR` or check against a range,...). Isn't there an according Class in java already present for this purpose?

Comment: Create a `Set` that contains all the errorcodes and...well write `CLIENT_ERROR.contains(code);`? Is this a trick question?

Comment: Add all of the integers in the range `400..499` to the `CLIENT_ERROR` `Set`...?

Comment: Use Guava's `Range.closedOpen(400, 500)`?

Comment: I thought there might be some predefined java class which does the trick for me...? I don't want to take care of having to maintain a set on my own for this.

Comment: This might help: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.Family http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.Family.html#CLIENT_ERROR

Comment: Or create your own private method for readability `boolean in400Range(int status){return (status /4) == 1;)}`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm actually utilizing `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.Family` now. Thank you @Kon for the useful hint!

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.Family;

if (Family.familyOf(responseCode) == Family.CLIENT_ERROR) {
```

Comment: `Response.Status.Family.CLIENT_ERROR == response.getStatusInfo().getFamily()`

Answer (score 26):

If using Spring you can simply do :

```
    HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode).is4xxClientError()
```

You can also look at [is4xxClientError()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.java#L493) implementation if you need anything extra